# Rhino setting a NativeObject property in java

Tags: java, rhino

I have a javascript script which when evaluated returns a NativeObject

```
obj = context.evaluateString(scope,"({age:3, name:'bob'})", "<source">, 1, null)
```

I then cast obj as either a NativeObject or Map and then run the put method

```
castObj.put("surname","smith")
```

And I get an java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException thrown.  Is there another way I can change the object value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should call the `NativeObject.put(String, Scriptable, Object)` version, not the `put(String, Object)` inherited from the `Map` interface:

```
public class AddPropertyToObject {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ContextFactory().call(new ContextAction(){

            @Override
            public Object run(Context ctx) {
                Scriptable scope = ctx.initStandardObjects();
                try {
                    Scriptable entity = ctx.newObject(scope);

                    NativeObject result = (NativeObject) ctx.evaluateString(
                        scope,
                        "({age:3, name:'bob'})",
                        "<inline>", 1, null);

                    result.put("surname", result, "Smith");

                    for (Entry<Object, Object> p : result.entrySet()) {
                        System.out.println(p.getKey() + ": " + p.getValue());
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                }
                return null;
            }
        });   
    }
}
```

Comment: I know what the issue was, the put(key, value) method doesn't work, it need the put(key, scriptable, value) method.  Cheers

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't notice you used that `Map` method :)